# regex match strings with specific string at nth to last word

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to regex match strings with a specific string at the "nth" to last word.

In this case words with the string "call" in them at the second to last word.

Most successful thing I have tried:

```
/.*(?=.*call.*)(\w+)\s(\w+)$/
```

The response I'm getting and what i'm looking for:

- "a phone call she" --> should return --> "a phone call she"
- "they were calling with" --> should return --> "they were calling with"
- **"you should call" --> is matching but shouldn't**
- "your call is ready" --> doesn't match currently and shouldn't

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm using Elasticsearch

Comment: It probably is I just couldn't seem to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are using a lookahead `(?=...)` which is confusing things.  That's matching your regular expression which must then be followed by the word `call`. Maybe you meant to use a non-capturing group: `(?:...)`?

```
/.*(?:.*call.*)(\w+)\s(\w+)$/
```

You don't actually need that though because ungrouped things also don't capture:

```
/.*call.*(\w+)\s(\w+)$/
```

After you've changed that you have the problem that after "call" you're matching 
"any characters any number of times followed by 1 or more word characters followed by a space and 1 or more word characters".

That would match:

> call with lots of words after it as long as there are two at the end

But not:

> call me

Because there wouldn't be at least two words after call.

I think you want to match strings ending with "call followed by any number of word characters, a space, and any number of word characters":

```
/.*call(\w*)\s(?:\w+)$/
```

If you do in fact want to match "call" and the subsequent words, you can change the capturing/non-capturing groups as appropriate.

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/iR8fS9)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you don't need to use lookahead/behind...

You just need regex which check if you have something then "call", then eventually something else, then whitespace, then another word and end of string.

```
/.*call[^\s]*\s[A-Za-z]+$/
```

I think you need this regex.